# Android : SQLite storage in Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: android, sqlite, google-api

Can I use Google Cloud Storage API to storage a SQLite database; which includes few string, integer values and a image? If I cannot, which API should I use, can anyone help me?
EDIT: I want to store these datas online and they should be always changeable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store ANY kind of data on Google Storage, as long as it meets there terms of services(which excludes pornography and perhaps other content I believe).  You cannot do operations on the database once it is in GS, such as updates and inserts.  You can only upload the entire database as a blob.  If you are looking for a functional datastore to access individual records you may want to look at Appengine's datastore or SQL offering, or dozens of other cloud services out there.